# Django Static Image in Form Update

Tags: django, nginx, django-forms, django-templates, django-staticfiles

In dev environment I can load the form and update any text field, django automatically handles the static images.

Where as in production static image handled by webservice, it loads the image in form update view, but it asks again to select the image in every update. It does not recognize the existing image, I know I have to handle it in views, but not sure how it is done generally. Pls help fix it.

models.py

```
 class Shop(models.Model):

name        = models.CharField('Shop Name', max_length=200)
    address     = models.CharField('Door numb, Building',        max_length=100    )
    street      = models.CharField('Street Name',        max_length=100                        )
    sublocal    = models.CharField('Area (if any)',        max_length=100,blank=True,null=True )
    location    = models.CharField('Locality',        max_length=100                        )
    //
    landmark    = models.CharField('Landmark/Complex/Mall (If any, )', max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    phone        = models.CharField('Phone Number', max_length=100)
    //
    pfimage        =    models.ImageField('Profile Photo', upload_to='shop/%Y',)

    pfimage_thumb        =   ImageSpecField(source='pfimage',
                                            processors=[Transpose(),ResizeToFill(200, 150), Adjust(contrast=1.2, sharpness=1.1)],
                                            format='JPEG',
                                        options={'quality': 95})

    uid         =models.CharField('Shop URL (optional) - shopmapy.com/< pincode>/', max_length=100, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
@csrf_protect
@login_required
def shopreregister(request, qs):
    vshop = Shop.objects.filter(user__username=request.user) 
    shop =    get_object_or_404(vshop, pk=qs)
    print shop
    form = ShopForm(data = request.POST or None, instance=shop)
    form.fields['name'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
    form.fields['uid'].widget.attrs['editable'] = True
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        if form.is_valid():
            #form['user'] = request.user
            f = form.save(commit=False)
            f.user = request.user
            f.company = Company.objects.get(name='Common')
            f.save()
            form.save_m2m()

            shopid = form.instance.id
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']

            return redirect('vendor-shop' , shopid) #thing='%s Registered' %name)

    return render(request, 'shopregister.html', {'form':form})
```

template:

```
{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <table border="0">
        {{ form }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: can you provide us with a code sample please?

Comment: @EmettSpeer Have added the code, please guide me ASAP.

Comment: Add initial data for `pfimage` if its not post. Also why are you making uid editable and name read only here?

Comment: You are right I removed the readonly for Name, but the actual problem still exists with initial data population. I changed : form = ShopForm(data = request.POST or None,initial={'pfimage':shop.pfimage,}, instance=shop) but still same problem, Am I doing wrong here?